# Json Script Won't Properly Run

Tags: python, file, web-scraping

So I'm writing a script to take a .txt file and

1. Attach string representation of each line
2. Attach a string in the beginning and end of the document.

So

> Hey there,
>
> My name is Jim and I'm excited to begin working for Microsoft. I
> believe my job history fits perfectly within the Microsoft Culture.
>
> Thanks! Jim

Would become

Hey there,\n My name is Jim and I'm excited to begin working for Microsoft. I believe my job history fits perfectly within the Micorosoft Culture. \nThanks! \nJim

While also attaching the following to the beginning

```
{"prompt":"", "completion":"
```

and the following at the end

```
"}
```

Now I have the following script that successfully takes up to 2 .txt and creates the string representation and attaches the needed keys in the front and end, but it can't do more than 2 PLUS gets the following error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

The Script

```
import sys
import os
import json
import os


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Please add a directory")
    sys.exit(0)

directory = sys.argv[1]

new_dir = os.path.abspath(directory+"/script_output")

if not os.path.isdir(new_dir):
    os.mkdir(new_dir)

for f_str in os.listdir(directory):

    if os.path.isdir(os.path.abspath(directory+f_str)):
        continue

    json_data = {}
    json_data["prompt"] = ""
    f_abs = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory, f_str))

    og_file = new_dir + "/" + f_str
    json_file = new_dir + "/" + os.path.splitext(f_str)[0] + ".json"

    f = open(f_abs, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    new_txt = repr(f.read())[1:-1]
    json_data["completion"] = new_txt

    with open(json_file, "w") as output_file:
        json.dump(json_data, output_file)

print("Done")
```

[image: Here you can see the full error]

EDIT 1:

As you can see, I have 2 text files that should turn into Json files within the script_output folder. When I run the comment code, there are no errors but the files don't appear.

[image]

Comment: Seems obviously a file permission issue. You could strip down the problem by simply trying to open the file and see how it works; the rest are irrelevant.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error may suggests that you use directory in `open()`. Maybe first check what you have in `f_abs`.

Comment: you big mistake is `directory+f_str` which creates wrong path `directoryfilename` instead of `directory/filename` - and `isdir()` gives `False`. You should use `directory + "/" + f_str` or better use `os.path.join(directory, f_str)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty clear.

The user in who's context your script is running doesn't have read permission on file: C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Rank\script_output

Is it running as a batch job so a different user?

Another problem maybe related. You are not closing that file after opening it. And you are opening the input file in a loop.

Also what should this line do? Because it does nothing

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.abspath(directory+f_str)):
    continue
```

One notices you use a context manager for the output file:

```
with open(json_file, "w") as output_file:
```

Similarly you should use

```
with open(f_abs, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are not using the correct directory to load the file from. I am assuming you want to load a file `2.txt` (something like that) which is stored inside `/script_output/` folder.

Try to run the file from the place where you have `script_output` folder and run like `python stack.py .`, I use `.` for the current directory and named my script as `stack.py` to illustrate an example.

Please try using the following script:

```
import sys
import os
import json
import os


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Please add a directory")
    sys.exit(0)

directory = sys.argv[1]

new_dir = os.path.abspath(directory+"/script_output")

if not os.path.isdir(new_dir):
    os.mkdir(new_dir)

for f_str in os.listdir(new_dir):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.abspath(new_dir+f_str)):
        continue

    json_data = {}
    json_data["prompt"] = ""
    f_abs = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(new_dir, f_str))

    og_file = new_dir + "/" + f_str
    json_file = new_dir + "/" + os.path.splitext(f_str)[0] + ".json"

    f = open(f_abs, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    f = open(f_abs, "r")
    new_txt = repr(f.read())[1:-1]
    json_data["completion"] = new_txt

    with open(json_file, "w") as output_file:
        json.dump(json_data, output_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! So the file runs, but the output isn't being generated anymore. The "Script_output" folder is supposed to take the files within the directory, and output a new json version within the folder. See edit 1

Comment: The file will be generated inside `script_output/` and I wrote the code such that the input file also needs to be present inside `script_output/`

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but for me all problem is that you create path using `+` instead of `os.path.join()`

When you check `isdir()` you use `directory+f_str` which creates string `directoryscript_output` instead `directory/script_output` and then `isdir()` returns `False` and later it tries to run `open("directory/script_output")` - so it tries to open directory - and this gives your error.

You wouldn't have this problem if you would use `os.path.join()`

---

My version (with other changes):

I check also extension `.txt` to make sure I read correct file.

I use more readable variables.

```
import os
import sys
import json

#directory = sys.argv[1]
directory = "test"

input_dir  = os.path.abspath(directory)  # later I will no need `abspath()`
output_dir = os.path.join(input_dir, "script_output")

os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)  # doesn't need `if`

for name in os.listdir(input_dir):
    input_path = os.path.join(input_dir, name)
    #print('input_path:', input_path)
    
    if os.path.isdir(input_path):
        print('dir:', input_path) 
        continue

    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(name)

    if ext != '.txt':
        print('wrong ext:', input_path)
        continue

    print('>>> processing:', input_path)
    
    json_data = {}
    json_data["prompt"] = ""
    
    json_file = os.path.join(output_dir, basename + ".json")

    with open(input_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json_data["completion"] = f.read()[1:-1]

    with open(json_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(json_data, f)

print("Done")
```